# Clip content inside div with another div

Tags: html, css

I am working on some kind of drawing app. 
There are elements inside a container div, and there is another div on top that should clip all the elements inside if it.

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/n6m4n750/

The red rectangle `"#clip` must clip all the elements inside `#container` div, so any elements or part of an element that is outside of the `#clip` div, will be hidden.

How is it possible to do that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can't you just have all the descendants of #container be inside #clip instead? Perhaps using pure markup and css for a drawing is setting yourself up a very steep challenge.

Comment: When you can ignore IE, maybe you can work with [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) and SVG Items. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: This is just a demo, the real app is much more complex and unfortunately I can't modify the HTML so descendants of #container will be inside #clip. So I must find another solution...

Answer (score 2):

Add the following css to `#clip`:

```
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 25px white;
```

Here, the white shadow of the `#clip` overlaps the contents that need to be clipped which gives a ***clipping effect***.

Here's a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n6m4n750/2/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Not really posible to really clip it, as far as I know.

If your background is white, you can simulate the idea givind a huge white shadow around it

```
#clip {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid 2px red;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1000px white;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n6m4n750/1/)

Comment: Nice idea, but the #container must be visible... It will have a background image applied to it... any other idea?

Comment: Can't you really modify your HTML ?

Comment: This is just a demo, the real app is much more complex and unfortunately I can't modify the HTML so descendants of #container will be inside #clip. So I must find another solution...

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't modify the html, i dont see a pure css solution. Maybe you could track the clipping with js.

```
const computeClip=function(target,mask){
    let maskRect = mask.getBoundingClientRect();
    let targetRect=target.getBoundingClientRect();;
    let clip='rect('
        +(maskRect.top-targetRect.top)+'px,'
        +(maskRect.left+maskRect.width-targetRect.left)+'px,'
        +(maskRect.top+maskRect.height-targetRect.top)+'px,'
        +(maskRect.left-targetRect.left)+'px)';
    target.style.clip=clip;

};
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9k17qwa2/)